# Doctrine: How to create entity-related tables on demand? (if i want to keep one SQL schema source)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Is there a way to tell Doctrine the name of a number of entities and it creates their related tables (incl. foreign keys etc.)?**

---

**My scenario:**

I want to have annotations at my Doctrine entities as the only source for my database schema. Which means, that for instance for tests, i don't want to maintain a *copy* of these information in a SQL file or something.

To be clear, i mean annotations in entity classes like the following:

```php
<?php 

namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *      uniqueConstraints={
 *          @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="email", columns={"email"})
 *      }
 * )
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    // ...
}
```

---

**What i would like to do:**

In my tests i would like to create the table for, lets say `User`, like:

```php
<?php


namespace App\Test;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class SomeTestCase extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        // ...

        $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }

    public function test1()
    {
        // Is there a function available which has this functionality?
        $this->entityManager->createTableForEntity('App\Entity\User'); // <---------

        // ...
    }
}
```

**Is that possible?** If not, even creating all tables at once is fine for me.

**Is there another way to achieve it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following to create all the tables in my tests:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;

$metadatas = $this->entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
$schemaTool = new SchemaTool($this->entityManager);
$schemaTool->updateSchema($metadatas);
```

There is a method `getMetadataFactory()` on the MetadataFactory class so I guess the following should work as well if you want to create just one table.

```
$metadata = $this->entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor('App\Entity\User');
$schemaTool = new SchemaTool($this->entityManager);
$schemaTool->updateSchema($metadata);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Will check that soon.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I started working with your code and it seems for Doctrine `2.7` you have to use an array for `updateSchema` (according to the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/tools.html#database-schema-generation)). The first part (with `getAllMetadata`) i didn't test yet.